# How do you access the Z axis in Tiff's when they are converted to a numpy array? The shape is only in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When you convert a Tiff to a numpy array I can't access or control the Z axis. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Adding code

```
img = Image.open("annotation_50.tif")

imgarray = np.array(img)

print imgarray.shape()
```

Results in (160,228)
The x and y values are accurate but the z axis value isn't showing up. I would expect (168,228,264) because there are 264 images in the tiff, making it a 3D array.

Comment: can you give some minimal example code please

Comment: Sorry, added some code

Comment: Do you have scipy? If you do try scipy's imread and see if it opens with the proper dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing any of your code I don't know exactly what you are doing but here is a suggestion:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np

    img = Image.open('multi-tiff.tiff') #multi-tiff.tiff is your image
    individual_imgs = np.zeros(len_Z,len_Y,len_X) #input the proper size
    for i in range(len_of_multi-tiff.tiff):  #put in the length of the tiff stack
        individual_img[i,:,:] = img.seek(i)
```